# TypeError: Cannot call method "getThreads" of null

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Necesito implementar el siguiente código para la eliminación masiva de correos electrónicos en una cuenta de Gmail (el código no es mio), pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
function cleanUp() {
    var delayDays = 365 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash

    var maxDate = new Date();
    maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);

    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("delete me");
    var threads = label.getThreads();
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
        {
            threads[i].moveToTrash();
        }
    }
}

function archiveInbox() {
    // Every thread in your Inbox that is read, older than two days, and not labeled "delete me".
    var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox is:read older_than:2d -label:"delete me"');
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i].moveToArchive();
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, me lanza error en la linea 8 con el siguiente mensaje:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getThreads" of null

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Si el código no es tuyo, ¿de quién es? :) Lo apropiado es dar la atribución del contenido tomado de otra parte. Lo mínimo es poner un enlace a la fuente, pero lo más apropiado es además del enlace a la fuente, incluir un  el nombre del autor del contenido referido y un enlace a su perfil.

Answer (score 1):

Me pasó una cosa parecida hace tiempo.

El problema lo tienes en

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("delete me");
```

Que pasa si no tienes mensajes con esa etiqueta? Lo lógico sería pensar que la función te devuelve una lista de 0 elementos, pero realmente lo que hace es devolverte un null.

La solución es mirar primero si te ha devuelto algo o no:

```
function cleanUp() 
{
    var delayDays = 365 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash

    var maxDate = new Date();
    maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);

    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("delete me");
    if(label != null)
    {
        var threads = label.getThreads();
        for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) 
        {
            if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
            {
                threads[i].moveToTrash();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.log("No hay mensajes a eliminar");
    }
}
```

No he probado el código pero estoy convencido que funciona.

Comment: He propuesto eliminar las líneas finales que son del tipo cierre de carta ya que esto debe evitarse para evitar dar pie a usar los hilos de preguntas/respuestas como si fuera un foro. La información básica sobre cómo responder se encuentra en [Cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Podrías encontrar más orientación al respecto en [meta].

Comment: Perfecto! Aún estoy muy verde... gracias!

Comment: recuerda q si te ha servido la respuesta deberias marcarla como correcta para que el resto de usuarios lo puedan aprovechar